# Nuget not installing the dll and the path is missing

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have an internal nuget repo on tfs, and when I install an internally created package, the "Packages" under "Dependencies" shows that it was installed, but with a yellow triangle w/ exclamation point. The package itself under "properties" shows only the Name and Version, but nothing else, like the path. Other internally built nuget packages install just fine.

When I manually download the nuget package, it has everything - the assets, the dll, the different other things. When I run the `install` command in the Package Manager Console using `-verbose`, I see no errors. The [troubleshooting help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting) from Microsoft isn't helping in this case.

I am not sure what else I could do to figure out why this is happening. Help?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is a "Projects" folder in list of Dependencies, and it must be taking precedence and not allowing the nuget package to get properly installed. Once I removed that dependency, the nuget package installed with no problems.